# Whether asynchronous HttpWebrequest is better than Synchronous Httpwebrequest for an ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net web page, which is accessed simultaneously by multiple users.
I am invoking a WebPage hosted in a remote server from this web page.  Which method is beneficial-asynchronous HttpWebRequest or synchronous HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean under "beneficial".
If it means the ease of coding, ease of avoiding browser-based problems and so on - then I'd go for synch.
If it means more flexibility for you as for developer but way harder way to handle it correctly then sure thing I'd go for asynch.

Just for a simple example - synchronous will prevent your users from doing anything else while they wait for the request to complete or time out, but asynch will let them do whatever else you'll want users to be able to do.

The point in using synchronous is that either you need that^ or the ease for you as for developer.